# how to use "count" feature?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw something like this. 
[image]

But I am not able to get x1,x2, ..., x5 labels. What I am getting is as follows:

[image]

So, I included count feature. My code is as follows :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\tikzset{input/.style={}} 
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle,draw}}


\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [block, right=1cm of input,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2.5cm] (a) { };
\node [block, right of=a,minimum width=3cm, minimum height=5cm,node distance=5cm] (b) {};


\begin{scope}[->,>=latex]

\draw[->] (input) -- (a);

\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {2,...,-2}{% 
\draw[->] ([yshift=\i * 0.4 cm]a.east) -- ([yshift=\i * 0.8 cm]b.west) node[right]{\footnotesize{$x_{\xi}$}} ;}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I am getting a compilation error like this:

```
 Use of \i doesn't match its definition ... node[right]{\footnotesize{$x_{\xi}$}} ;}
```

Comment: Works just fine with me. Maybe you have an older version of `tikz` and should update?

Comment: The `count` feature was added to PGF for version 2.1; however, older TeX distros just ship version 2.0. So my first assumption would be that your PGF package is a bit outdated.

Comment: Add `\pgfversion` after `\begin{document}`to see your pgf version

Comment: When you post code it is preferable create a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with the documentclass and packages you use.

Comment: I had installed it using Synaptic Package Manager. How do I update it now ?

Answer (score 2):

No problem to compile but in your example you need to use the library `positioning`. I think it's preferable to give us a complete example, to see if a conflict appears between packages.
It's interesting also when you get an error like this to give us the version of the packages that you used.

You can find a lot of examples on tex.se with `[count=\xi]`.

> ```
>   /pgf/foreach/count=⟨macro⟩from⟨value⟩ (no default)
> ```
>
> This key allows
>   ⟨macro⟩ to hold the position in the list of the current item. The
>   optional from ⟨value⟩ statement allows the counting to begin from
>   ⟨value⟩.

By default the first value of `\xi` is 1, and you can count the number of iterations for -2 to 2 the last value is 5.